# Set Default/Global Python3 Regex Flag

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I can make a regex ignore case by passing re.compile the re.I flag. I'd like to ignore case every time. Is it possible to set default flags for re.compile, so I don't have to set them every time?

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own function/method to mimic this behaviour. It would be something like this:

```py
import re

def my_re_compile(pattern, flags=0):
    return re.compile(pattern, flags | re.I)


my_pattern = my_re_compile(r"my case insensitive sentence")

# should print: My case Insensitive sentence
print(my_pattern.search("My case Insensitive sentence").group(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, you can use an [inline flag / modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) *ie.* `(?i)` along with your *regex* to ignore case.

```
regex = r"(?i)[a-z]"
```